# Template data binding in backbone is not working without extra parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, data-binding

Am using template in backbone js and I bind the data like following:

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template : '<div data-bind="text:username" class="mydiv1"></div><div data-bind="text:username" class="mydiv2"></div>',

    config: {
        widgetFontColor : null,
        widgetFontSize : null
    },
});
```

Note: this is a snippet from my test js.

As you see I have two divs with same data :username with different class.

I have a text input field and a button in html. When I type something in input and click on submit button the text should be displayed twice in same page with different styles.

Below is the method called when clicking on submit.

```
var publishUsername = function () {
    var username = getString('username');
    hub.publish ('widgetTestTopic', { username :  username});
};
```

But here only one div is being displayed.i.e Only first div is displayed.

But when I add a parent tag(either div or span) in template like below, the text is displayed twice as expected. i.e both the div's are displayed.

```
template : '<div><div data-bind="text:username" class="mydiv1"></div><div data-bind="text:username" class="mydiv2"></div></div>',
```

Please help me with the understanding why a parent tag is required to display both the div's.

Am calling below function to render the view

```
_renderView: function () {
        if (this._isDataReady()) {
            this.$el.html('');

            if (this.testView) {
                this.testView.destroy();
            }
            this.testView = this.create('test_view_testView', TestView, {
                el: this.$el,
                viewModel: this.viewModel,
                data : {
                    username : this.viewModel.get('username')
                }
            });
        } 
        else {
            this.$el.html('Data not available');
        }
    },
```

Comment: Backbone does not come with data binding in templates by default, you must be using a plugin. Which plugin are you using for data binding?

Comment: @kmiyashiro am using KO for data binding.Sorry for not mentioning it on first hand.

Comment: Can you include your render method as well to help us figure out what's going on?

Comment: @Cameron Hi, I have added my render method. Appreciate your help!! :)

Comment: @Mahendira, thanks.  I'm trying to see where your template html actually gets added to the page which I don't see here.  Looks like this.create probably creates an instance of TestView and maybe TestView's render function renders the template html?  In any case, can you also add the relevant bits between _renderView and where the template is actually rendered?